# RSSI through Multipeer Connectivity Framework

Tags: ios, p2p, multipeer-connectivity, rssi

Is it possible to detect the signal strength of a connection between two iOS devices by using Multipeer Connectivity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. I think there is a good reason for this. As you can read in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/index.html):

> The Multipeer Connectivity framework provides support for discovering
>   services provided by nearby iOS devices using infrastructure Wi-Fi
>   networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth personal area networks and
>   subsequently communicating with those services by sending
>   message-based data, streaming data, and resources (such as files).

In case of infrastructure Wi-Fi network, there is no direct connection between two iOS devices as they communicate through an access point. Therefore you can't get the signal strength of a connection, because it simply doesn't exist.

If you want to get RSSI, you can use Core Bluetooth framework instead.

Comment: Thank you, so the only way to get an RSSI value is through Core Bluetooth. I tried this method but I also wanted to implement another RSSI measurement in order to have a more accurate distance estimation.

Comment: Technically you can also advertise as iBeacon on one device (it still requires Core Bluetooth) and use Core Location to scan for beacons on another one. But this approach has it limitations (like not being able to advertise as iBeacon when app is in the background).

Comment: Yeah I know, I'm also taking this into account

Comment: However the issue of iBeacon could be solved through regular location updates